# I'm seeing this error ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading '_rawValidators') what could be an issue

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I'm writing chrome extension btw, so I'm seeing this error in the background under the Error tab in the extensions tab.

FIXED: I can see it in console as well:
main.412519c570eac939.js:1 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading '_rawValidators')

I'm having a problem with this error. I checked other posts and the error was related to the bad naming of formcontrol or using ngModel with formControl, but that's not my case I believe.
I'm also using Angular Material Stepper, and this code is placed inside one of the steps:

```
<mat-step label="Object/Fields" [stepControl]="SOQLObject">
```

My HTML Code:

```
<form [formGroup]="SOQLObject" class="col-3">
                    <section class="object-input">
                        <div formGroupName="objectStep">
                            <label for="typeahead-focus">
                                Select Object:
                            </label>
                            <input
                                type="text"
                                class="form-control"
                                [ngbTypeahead]="search"
                                (focus)="focus$.next($any($event).target.value)"
                                (click)="click$.next($any($event).target.value)"
                                #objectSelect="ngbTypeahead"
                                formControlName="objectInput"
                            />
                        </div>
                        <!-- Empty field -->
                        <div
                            style="align-self: end; margin-top: 15px"
                            *ngIf="ObjectInputCT.dirty"
                        >
                            <button
                                mat-icon-button
                                (click)="resetObjectSelect()"
                                title="Clear the Selected Object"
                            >
                                <mat-icon>arrow_back</mat-icon>
                            </button>
                        </div>
                    </section>
                </form>
```

TS:

```
SOQLObject = this._formBuilder.group({
        objectStep: this._formBuilder.group({
            objectInput: ["", Validators.required],
        }),
    });

ObjectInputCT = this.SOQLObject.controls["objectStep"].controls["objectInput"];

ngOnInit(): void {
        this.ObjectInputCT.valueChanges.subscribe((val) => {
            if (!this.OBJECTSLIST.includes(val as string)) {
                this.ObjectInputCT.setErrors({ invalid: true });
            } else {
                this.ObjectInputCT.setErrors(null);
                this.ObjectInputCT.disable({
                    onlySelf: true,
                    emitEvent: false,
                });
                this.objectSelectChild.dismissPopup();
            }
            if (val == "" || val == " ") {
                this.ObjectInputCT.markAsPristine();
            }
        });
    }
```

If I remove the disable() function the error disappears but I need this to disable input.

I created StackBlitz project but it doesn't show the error(
[https://stackblitz-starters-g4tvjn.stackblitz.io](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-g4tvjn?file=src%2Fmain.ts)

Answer (score 1):

We can write a custom validator, instead of relying on the valueChanges to perform the validation, hopefully it will resolve the issue since its not reproducible!

Keyword Validator

```
export function KeywordValidator(
  keywords: Array<string>,
  control: AbstractControl
) {
  debugger;
  if (keywords.includes(control.value)) {
    return { invalidUrl: true };
  }
  return null;
}
```

main.ts

```
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {
  AbstractControl,
  FormBuilder,
  FormsModule,
  ReactiveFormsModule,
  Validators,
} from '@angular/forms';
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import 'zone.js';

export function KeywordValidator(
  keywords: Array<string>,
  control: AbstractControl
) {
  debugger;
  if (keywords.includes(control.value)) {
    return { invalidUrl: true };
  }
  return null;
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root1',
  standalone: true,
  templateUrl: 'main.html',
  imports: [FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule, CommonModule],
})
export class App {
  constructor(private _formBuilder: FormBuilder) {}
  OBJECTSLIST: Array<string> = ['Hello', 'World'];

  SOQLObject = this._formBuilder.group({
    objectStep: this._formBuilder.group({
      objectInput: [
        '',
        [Validators.required, KeywordValidator.bind(this, this.OBJECTSLIST)],
      ],
    }),
  });

  ObjectInputCT =
    this.SOQLObject.controls['objectStep'].controls['objectInput'];

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.ObjectInputCT.valueChanges.subscribe((val) => {
      if (this.ObjectInputCT?.errors?.['invalidUrl']) {
        this.ObjectInputCT.disable({
          onlySelf: true,
          emitEvent: false,
        });
      }
      if (val == '' || val == ' ') {
        this.ObjectInputCT.markAsPristine();
      }
    });
  }
}

bootstrapApplication(App);
```

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-dbmf2z?file=src%2Fmain.ts,src%2Fmain.html)

Comment: Thanks for your response. Unfortunately, it has no effect I'm still seeing this error(

Comment: I found a workaround, instead of disabling input via FormControl I can update 
[read-only] param on the Input, does the same but I just don't like how it looks from the developer's point. Thanks

Comment: I found the real issue, I've created this as a placeholder in HTML:
"<section formGroupName="">Hello World</section>"

Now it perfectly works. Sometimes I'm impressed by my stupidity. Thanks again for your time!

Comment: @Colder_Host no problem it happens, gald it's resolved!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [read-only]="boolean" and update boolean variable in the valueChanges function:

```
<input
    type="text"
    class="form-control"
    [readonly]="test"
    formControlName="objectInput"
/>
```

Additionally, you can update how the input will look when it's read-only:
F.e:

```
.form-control:read-only {
        pointer-events: none;
        background-color: #e9ecef;
        opacity: 1;
    }
```